# How to conclude the convergence of the this Taylor Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$

Tags: calculus

I've encountered a question I seem to have no idea how to solve or approach. I would greatly appreciate any hint or explanation of what is the correct answer, and why.

If $\ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable $n$ times and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ is the Taylor Series expansion around $0$ such that: 
$f(1) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

which of the following is correct:

1. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n \cdot a_n}{n} $ converges
2. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((-1)^n \cdot a_n) $ converges
3. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{ ((-1)^n \cdot a_n)} {2^n} $ converges absolutely
4. $f(0.5) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{2^n} $

Edited:

1. The correct answer is 3. I have no idea why.
2. Someone helped me edit the question, but option (iii) was somehow edited incorrectly. Updated it now.

Comment: I think $f$ needs to be infinitely differentiable at $0$.

Comment: The statement of this problem is a bit of a mess, as hinted by Tunococ.  You say $f$ is differentiable $n$ times, but $n$ is a summation index.

Answer (score 3):

This question is really testing your recognition of [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). Your power series is centered around $0$, and the fact that it converges for $x = 1$ means that the radius is at least $1$. This tells you nothing about $-1$ or $2$, nor do you know about the related-yet-different-series described by option $1$.

However, $\frac{1}{2}$ is certainly contained within a ball of radius $1$ around the origin, so we know option $4$ is correct.

Comment: Even if we know that $\sum a_n*0.5^n$ converges, can we be sure that it converges to $f(0.5)$ ? (this is really a question)

Comment: This is precisely what Abel's Theorem proves — if the series $\sum_k{a_k} R^k$ converges and $\sum_k{a_k} x^k$ has a radius of convergence $R$, then $\sum_k{a_k} x^k\xrightarrow[x\to R]{} \sum_k{a_k} R^k$.

Comment: Well it seems as though the correct answer (at-least as appearing in my textbox) is 3.  Why is this?